# Connect to XMPPRoom

Tags: iphone

Im using XMPPframework to create a chat for iphone. Im trying to connect the user to a certain chat room, but I can't do it.

This is the code I have:

```
BOOL activado = [salaChat activate:[[self appDelegate] xmppStream]];    
[salaChat joinRoom];
[salaChat sendMessage:@"HELLO"];

BOOL unido = [salaChat isJoined];
```

Being salaChat a XMMPPRoom object.

"activado" is always true but "unido" never.

test_android is the username and "retiro" is the room id. Maybe the mistake is there but I tried many ways and still nothing.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

see http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-integration/

Comment: great tutorial but It doesnt use XMMPPRooms.

Comment: why do not you try http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS . It looks like more popular choice.

Comment: Docs moved from google to git. https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki

Answer (score -1):

Ok, solved it, I was putting wrong the name of the room.

It should be "roomid@conference.127.0.0.1" and nickname , the users nickname.